# Updated my macOS to Monterey 12.4 and installed XCode command lines and now my React Native app is not loading on the virtual emulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, xcode-tools

I'm building an app with React Native and Firebase, and I updated my Mac to macOS Monterey 12.4, and now my iOS Emulator is not loading with my app at all.

I keep getting this error message:

```
2022-05-18 12:43:55.803 xcodebuild[1548:12290] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-05-18 12:43:55.803 xcodebuild[1548:12290] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/matthewlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-dzjfebuyazpxwhdxydiigjjvnjjp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName normal (in target 'AppName' from project 'AppName')
(1 failure)
```

I heard that I needed to install new XCode tools, but I don't know the commands for that.

Please help me finally load my iOS Emulator so I can build my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xcode-select --install` command. it should install all the required tools.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I eventually fixed it by updating the pods.
Just try to run this command in your ios folder:

```
pod update && pod install
```